# Creating nonuniform grids for FDM with multiple points of concentration

Tags: finite-difference, finite-volume, multigrid, grid

If I am creating a grid in the $S_i$ direction with $N_S+1$ grid points. If I want more steps around some $K$, I can use:
$$
S_i=K+c \sinh \left(\xi_i\right), \quad i=0,1, \ldots, N_S
$$
where $c=\frac{K}{5}$, and;
$$
\xi_i=\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{-K}{c}\right)+i \Delta \xi
$$
with
$$
\Delta \xi=\frac{1}{N_S}\left[\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{S_{\max }-K}{c}\right)-\sinh ^{-1}\left(-\frac{K}{c}\right)\right]
$$

The result will be more grind points around $S_i\approx K$ and lesser points everywhere else. Is there any equivalent method for multiple points of "concentration" instead of just 1? I.e. $K_1$ and $K_2$, so the grid points will be finer around $K_1$ and $K_2$ and lesser points everywhere else?

Comment: Let $\xi_1(i)$ be a mapping providing refined resolution at $i_1$ and $\xi_2(i)$ be a mapping providing refined resolution at $i_2$. Then $\xi_3(i)= \xi_1*\xi_2/i$ should be the mapping providing refined resolution at both $i_1$ and $i_2$; it will be a piece-wise-linear function with reduced slope at those two locations.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I would have posted this as an answer to the question. To me, it seems to answer its key component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi_1()$ be a mapping providing refined resolution at $_1$ and $\xi_2()$ be a mapping providing refined resolution at $_2$. Then $\xi_3()=\xi_1 \xi_2/$ should be the mapping providing refined resolution at both $_1$ and $_2$; it will be a piece-wise-linear function with reduced slope at those two locations.

Here is an illustration of how this works: One mapping function (dash) is optimized for enhanced resolution at $x=0.55$, the other (dash-dot) for $x=0.3$; and the proposed combination of them (solid) has both.

[image]